How to merge columns from different data frames/txt files with different number of rows
I have several data frames (txt files), with the same number of columns (20), but different number of rows.
For instance,
Dimensions 11770x20



Gene_Id
Chr
Start
End
Length
Reads
TPM
ExonLength
ExonReads
ExonTPM




LOC117243535
NW_022882922.1
58793
59875
1083
8
0.510339
1083
8
0.289397


LOC117243589
NW_022882922.1
60266
61228
963
12
0.860899
614
6
0.382839


LOC117243573
NW_022882922.1
75178
81169
5992
41
0.472726
1051
31
1.15556


LOC117243530
NW_022882922.1
82581
87265
4685
3073
45.3158
3696
3067
32.5099


LOC117243513
NW_022882922.1
87408
92509
5102
1972
26.7032
3895
1957
19.6841


LOC117243540
NW_022882922.1
92501
93993
1493
817
37.8059
1386
816
23.0654


LOC117243522
NW_022882922.1
94375
99883
5509
9133
114.535
3477
9068
102.174



Dimensions  11683x20



Gene_Id
Chr
Start
End
Length
Reads
TPM
ExonLength
ExonReads
ExonTPM




LOC117243535
NW_022882922.1
58793
59875
1083
5
0.294678
1083
5
0.197168


LOC117243589
NW_022882922.1
60266
61228
963
13
0.861636
614
7
0.486882


LOC117243573
NW_022882922.1
75178
81169
5992
23
0.244998
1051
7
0.284439


LOC117243530
NW_022882922.1
82581
87265
4685
3012
41.0348
3696
2981
34.4448


LOC117243513
NW_022882922.1
87408
92509
5102
1565
19.5786
3895
1554
17.0388


LOC117243540
NW_022882922.1
92501
93993
1493
647
27.6599
1386
644
19.8434


LOC117243522
NW_022882922.1
94375
99883
5509
7499
86.8835
3477
7455
91.5666


LOC117234422
NW_022882922.1
101930
108153
6224
459
4.70706
3120
423
5.79002


LOC117234352
NW_022882922.1
108188
113107
4920
355
4.60543
3325
350
4.49542


LOC117230168
NW_022882922.1
114666
128596
13931
1666
7.63308
3119
1534
21.0041


LOC117230189
NW_022882922.1
128634
131497
2864
409
9.11501
2001
401
8.55838


LOC117230196
NW_022882922.1
131822
137028
5207
5569
68.2648
2303
5539
102.714



I want to loop through all the txt files and merge all the TPM columns to create a data frame/matrix, but my question/issue is that each dataframe/txt file has a different number of rows, hence, some rows might be present in file A but missing in file B and viceversa.
Thus, I need to properly match the rows using Gene_Id.
Thanks;
I thought about using dplyr or tidyverse but I am uncertain on how to make sure that rows are properly matched, so the matrix/data frame, is not messed up.

Do not post images of code and/or data. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of dput(head(<your data frame>)) if you have a large data frame.

It's not clear how you intend to use the data once all txt files are combined so this answer may not be the best way to format your data. However, based on your description, this code will join/combine all of your txt files by Gene_Id regardless of the number of rows.
For this example, I created tab delimited txt files using your example data and saved them in my working directory in a folder called "data". You will need to modify the file path "data/" to wherever your data are stored if this is not the case for you. Full paths can be used e.g. "C:/txt/file/location/".
Repeated TPM column names will have the source txt file name appended to ensure column names are unique and so you can keep track of your data.
# Create list of txt files from folder (e.g. "data" folder in working directory)
files <- list.files("data/",
                    pattern = "*.txt$", 
                    full.names = TRUE)
files
# [1] "data/flie_a.txt" "data/flie_b.txt"

# Read in all txt files, select only necessary columns, rename TPM with source
# txt file name
tpm <- lapply(files, function(x) {
  
  df <- read.table(x, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  tpm_df <- df[, c("Gene_Id", "TPM")]
  colnames(tpm_df)[2] <- paste0("TPM_", tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x)))
  return(tpm_df)
  
})

# Join all objects in tpm by Gene_Id
tpm_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "Gene_Id", all = TRUE), tpm)

tpm_df
#         Gene_Id TPM_flie_a TPM_flie_b
# 1  LOC117230168         NA   7.633080
# 2  LOC117230189         NA   9.115010
# 3  LOC117230196         NA  68.264800
# 4  LOC117234352         NA   4.605430
# 5  LOC117234422         NA   4.707060
# 6  LOC117243513  26.703200  19.578600
# 7  LOC117243522 114.535000  86.883500
# 8  LOC117243530  45.315800  41.034800
# 9  LOC117243535   0.510339   0.294678
# 10 LOC117243540  37.805900  27.659900
# 11 LOC117243573   0.472726   0.244998
# 12 LOC117243589   0.860899   0.861636

